# set height div to other element height on page

Tags: css, height, z-index

I've created this content with drupal. Below the image you have a next page button. 
I also set a button for next image on top of the image (pager) so if the visitor clicks on the image it would go next page.

How can i stretch the link over my image, drupal generated 2 divs and the images are variable in height.

```
<div class="view-content">
<div class="container12">
<div class="pagerfoto column12">
<h2 class="element-invisible">Pagina's</h2>
<div class="item-list">
<ul class="pager">
<li class="pager-next first">
<a href="/test/project11?page=1">›</a>
</li>
<li class="pager-last last">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container12">
<ul>
<li class="views-row views-row-1 column12">
<div>
<div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
<div class="field-content">
<img width="900" height="675" alt="" src="http://www.logicaarchitectuur.be/test/sites/default/files/styles/gallery_large/public/desert.jpg?itok=J6D4TAEL" typeof="foaf:Image">
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[site](http://www.logicaarchitectuur.be/test/project11)

```
        .pagerfoto{
        z-index:1;
        position:absolute;
        padding-top:1.71429em;
        display:block;
    }

    .pagerfoto ul li.pager-next a{
        display:block;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        text-indent: -9999px;   
    }
```

This is the current css i use for ma a label.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or some code snippet?

Comment: see post above, I've added some code

Comment: Did you try giving `background-image` to your `anchor` tag?

Comment: could you be more specific, the image must link to the next page

Comment: `<a href="/next_page_url" style="background-image:imageURL">&nbsp;</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this css:

```
.view-project11 {
    position: relative;
  }
 .item-list {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
 }
```

Comment: css not working. i will have to find a way that my a stretches with the div with the image.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you would like the user to click on the image and then the page will go to the next image.

wrapping your image in the  tag will allow you to do that.

example

```
<a width="900" height="675" href="/test/project11?page=1">
  <img width="900" height="675" alt="" src="http://www.logicaarchitectuur.be/test/sites/default/files/styles/gallery_large/public/desert.jpg?itok=J6D4TAEL" typeof="foaf:Image">
</a>
```

Comment: that is what i want, but not possible because of generated content with drupal